# Is using awk at least 'awk -F' always will be fine?

Tags: awk, linux-kernel

What is the difference on Ubuntu between `awk` and `awk -F`? For example to display the frequency of the cpu core 0 we use the command

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i "^ cpu MHz" | awk -F ":" '{print $ 2}' | head -1
```

But why it uses `awk -F`? We could put `awk` without the `-F` and it would work of course (already tested).

Comment: Please just look up `-F` in the awk man page. You never need cat, grep, and/or head when using awk btw. You're whole script can be reduced to `awk -F':' 'tolower($0) ~ /^ cpu mhz/{print $2; exit}' /proc/cpuinfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Because without -F , we couldn't find from wath separator i will begin the calculation and print the right result. It's like a way to specify the kind of separator for this awk's using. Without it, it will choose the trivial separator in the line like if i type on the terminal: ps | grep xeyes | awk '{print $1}' ; in this case it will choose the space ' ' as a separator to print the first value: pid OF the process xeyes. I found it in https://www.shellunix.com/awk.html. Thanks for all.